# C++ operator overloading with pointers

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

```
struct Test {
    int A = 0;
    int B = 0;
};

Test* operator+(const Test *x, const Test *r) {

    Test *test = new Test;
    test->A = x->A + r->A;
    test->B = x->B + r->B;
    return test;
}
```

Why this wont work and give's :

> 3 IntelliSense: nonmember operator requires a parameter with class or enum type

Comment: The message should be pretty clear, you can't use pointers. Also, doing this will give you memory leaks. Who will free the memory returned by the function?

Comment: Test x, r; 
 Test *test = (&x + &r); delete test;

Comment: @user3550045 Don't overuse pointers, especially raw pointers. Pointers were designed with a very specific point in mind, not for Java-like syntax in C++.

Comment: And when you have multiple additions in a row, like e.g. `a + b + c`? Or if you want to use addition as part of another expression, e.g. as argument to a function call? You're going to split it up into multiple statements and temporary variables too? Lot of work for something that should be simple.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently, the operator+ request that the first argument not be a pointer.
This would work:

```
Test* operator+(const Test &x, const Test& r){

    Test *test = new Test;
    test->A = x.A + r.A;
    test->B = x.B + r.B;
    return test;
}
```

But it's safer if you don't return a pointer, like Jonachim said.
You should do this:

```
Test operator+(const Test &x, const Test& r){

    Test test;
    test.A = x.A + r.A;
    test.B = x.B + r.B;
    return test;
}
```

Comment: Thats work - >  Test* operator+(const Test & x, const Test *r)

Comment: Good answer, I'd change *You could do this* to *You **should** do this*.

Comment: as you said it's looks you can't use the first argument as pointer wired !,, anyway thank's for the clarifying.

Comment: @user3550045, it is not weird. C++ clearly specifies that you can't overload operators for built-in types.

Comment: The first argument can be a pointer. All that's required is that at least one of the arguments is a user-defined type. That can be the first argument, or the second, or both.